# MYSQL query, is it possible to find after 7th digit of each product contains an "E"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MYSQL and trying to set a database.

In the future I will be creating queries to make reports on products sold.

My product code is as follows:

```
01CES22AEZ
```

Is it possible to create a query in MYSQL so that I can find products' code starts with "01" and "after 7th digit of each product(so i want to disregard characters before 7th digit)" contains "E".

I just need heads up on if this is possible to do.

Thanks

---

**Additional:**

OK I get the point.

If my product code is like `01CES22AEZ`

I can use

```
select 
  *
from
 tablename
where productcode like '01______E_';
```

BUT if my product code is like `01CES22AFDE` and I still want to products code that contains "E" 11th digit?

The above query wont work I guess?

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Comment: Yes, of course. There're endless ways, most of which will perform badly in very large datasets because they won't be using indexes. Have you tried something so far?

Comment: The only thing MySQL can't do is make a good cup of tea. But aside from that, I think this is a good question.

Comment: For 11th digit E, you have to place 8 times Hyphen(_) after 01

Comment: what is the status of this older question? If an answer did solve it  then it should be marked as solved by accepting an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you mean "after the 7th character", you can do this with regular expressions or with `like`:

```
where productcode like '01_____%Z%'
```

`like` is preferable in this case, because the pattern starts with constant characters (as opposed to `%` or `_`), so MySQL can use an index on the column.

If, perchance, you just want product codes that start with `01` and end with `Z`, then use:   `where productcode like '01_____%Z'`.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst the `like` might well perform better in this case, because it might be able to use the index (I'm afraid I don't know enough to know whether that's true or not) I thought it would also be worth answering with the regex option, since it is a useful option, particularly for smaller datasets.

You'd want something like:

```
SELECT something
FROM table
WHERE productcode REGEXP '^01.{5}(?:.*[E|e].*)$'
```

That matches an exact `01` at the start of the string (`^`) followed by any 5 characters, which we don't care about `.{5}`. The next section is a non-capturing group `(?: )` which will find an `E` or `e` anywhere in the remaining characters after the 7th character (by saying that there might be characters before it `.*` or after it. It will only find a match if all these things are found.

Comment: If you could perhaps explain  the parts/syntax of the REGEX and how they relate to the desired result, that would be great. Good idea to present an alernative to LIKE as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below:

```
select 
  *
from
 tablename
where productcode like '01______E_';
```

Because the series starts from 01 that is why I have take 01 in starting after that it could be any thing for next 6 character for that i have take 6 times hyphen(_) and 7th digit would be E and last character could be anything so again _. Hyphen is for any one character.

Comment: This lacks any explanaton as to the method why or how this may work

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: for 11th digit E, you have to place 8 times Hyphen(_)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Customers
 WHERE City LIKE '01______E%';
```

Comment: this lacks and sort of useful explanation.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the additional question posed by the OP:

> BUT if my product code is like 01CES22AFDE and I still want to
>   products code that contains "E" 11th digit?
>
> The above query wont work I guess?

You can do this with either `LIKE` or with `REGEX`.

**LIKE method:**

Because you want to count the number of spaces *before* `e` you can use the underscore as exampled by [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401237/3536236) :

```
where productcode like '__________E%'
```

this is 10x `_` and then `e`, meaning exactly 10 of any value and then an `e` and then anything afterwards. MySQL is usually not case sensitive.

**The REGEX Method:**

As well displayed by [CyberneticianDave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401419/3536236) REGEX can do almost exactly the same thing, with

```
WHERE productcode REGEXP '^.{10}(?:[E|e].*)$'
```

Which means that you have ten characters of anything from the start of the string, then an `e` or an `E` and then any characters after the string.

---

Overall I would have expected your addtional question to have been easily worked out from the answers already given. That's what I did.

Comment: I think from the OP he was looking for an E _anywhere_ after the 7th character, hence the extra percent in [Gordon's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36401237/1016336) answer and the preceeding `.*` in mine.

Comment: @CyberneticianDave the OPs further question stated they wanted to find the `e` as an 11th digit,

Comment: I read the extended question on being a clarification of fixed position matching. Some of the answers only search for an `E` in the 8th position; but since the original proposition was to find it anywhere after the 7th, the OP was checking what would happen if it was in the 11th position. Anything with fixed length matching would fail to match some of the possibilities.